# CMake generate Doxygen docs without new target

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt that generates Doxygen docs and compiles code with this content:

```
option(BUILD_DOC "Build documentation" ON)

find_package(Doxygen)

if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    set(DOXYGEN_IN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in)

    set(DOXYGEN_OUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile.out)

    configure_file(${DOXYGEN_IN} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} @ONLY)

    add_custom_target(my-project-docs ALL
            COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
            VERBATIM)
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

I can then select in CLion a target of 'my-project' and 'my-project-docs' which i assume is because 'add_custom_target', is there a way to not add 'my-project-docs' target and just generate documentation when i build 'my-project'?

I've tried deleting add_custom_target but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [a post-build custom command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) instead. I suppose something like (assuming you have a target named `my-project`):

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my-project POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ARGS ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)
```

Note from the docs: "*If the target is already built, the command will not execute.*" But I suppose that shouldn't be a problem if the source files containing the doc comments are all source files or headers of the target you attach the custom build-event command to, since changes to the doc comments will probably also cause the target to rebuild. Unless you have a super smart buildsystem that is comment-aware.